# Getting the SQL queries of an Enterprise Architecture database

Tags: mysql, sql, enterprise-architect

I am currently trying to create an automatic mssql task to generate a baseline like the Enterprise Architecture program does.

I have tried querying the DB for the last queries performed on the same DB; 
is it possible, from those queries, to find the ones that take the baseline and perform them again, at a scheduled time?
To get the sql queries after the baseline started to be created and when it finished:

```
SELECT  dest.text 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
    WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > '04/08/2016 15:23:45' 
       AND deqs.last_execution_time < '04/08/2016 15:33:45';
```

Comment: It helps if you format the question as a -- question --, you know, with a question mark and stuff. Now it just looks like you are telling us something you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong approach here. You should not try to do that with SQL.

Enterprise Architect provides an API that you can use to create a new baseline. See [Project Interface](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/project_2.html) and look for the operations `CreateBaseline()` and `CreateBaselineEx()`